# Help identifying connectors from an art project

Tags: connector

I am working on getting an art project with poor documentation back into working shape, and as part of that I'd like to identify some of its electrical connectors so I can purchase some interoperable parts. I've looked through image-based catalogs in Digi-Key and tried browsing Molex's catalog without success.

There are two that are giving me trouble at the moment:

#### 5-pin connector

(I recognize that this connector is being used as a 4-pin device…I don't know the original design intent but they likely didn't want this one to be interoperable with the other connector listed.)

5-pin connector side view:

[image: 5-pin side]

5-pin connector front view:

[image: 5-pin front]

#### 4-pin connector

4-pin connector side view:

[image: 4-pin side]

4-pin connector front view:

[image: 4-pin front]

Any leads (including useful search services) much appreciated!

Comment: Those connectors look mangled. I'd consider replacing them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I may well do so—but would prefer to replace with the same type if possible. (Hence the identification question.)

Comment: Maybe Molex Power Connector?

Comment: @Tyler Molex is a manufacturer, not a type of connector. And no, this clearly isn't the 4-pin MATE-N-LOK power connector that most people think of when they hear "Molex connector".

Comment: it is a 5 pin version of this https://www.parts-express.com/pedocs/specs/Molex%2015%20way%20092-566s.pdf .... it appears to be obsolete

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for that. The accepted answer below is pointing to something that looks identical or nearly-identical to what you found. (I actually can't confirm at the moment as apparently molex.com is down?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something similar

comes in 1 to 10 contact versions

[image]

https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=econolatch&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_wire_connectors

this one  is closer

https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0003091042_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

[image]

https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0003091052_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

[image]

Comment: Yep, I think you found the match. Thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating whats already been said but personally I would replace the connectors with anything that resembles the connectors currently on the project and document the changes appropriately so the project can be easily maintained.

A suggestion to help finding a replacement part as well... try posting front view images (last image posted) with both metric and imperial tape measures showing dimensions.
This will help people recognise conductor fitting diameters and conductor fitting spacings... hope this helps ! :)

Comment: I am working at a borrowed workspace with very few tools, and was lucky to even find an imperial tape measure. But yes, you're right, having fiducials in both systems is best if possible.

Answer (score 0):

They look much like the nylon connectors make by AMP (now TE/AMP) and Molex for many years.  Molex makes ones that look just like yours in fact. Both AMP and Molex will have their names molded into them but they may be hard to see. These days there are probably a number of numbers of companies out of China that make ones just like yours.

Comment: I looked carefully but didn't end up finding any markings on the parts other than the [1] and [4] pin identifiers that @jaysotola 's answer includes. Either mine was a knockoff part, or I couldn't see the logo because it was white on white.

Comment: The Molex ones I have have "Molex" on the "ears".